# Android Studio wizard buttons hidden behind Windows TaskBar

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have a problem with any wizard that its height more than or equal my screen height in android studio, the issue simply that the buttons hidden under Windows TaskBar, see the following image : 
[image: the buttons under taskbar]

I have the latest Android Studio IDE 1.3 build AI-141.2117773
My JDK version is 8 Update 45, on Windows 10 Pro (build 10240)
My Screen resolution 1366 x 768 (for laptop 15 inches screen)

Any solution for this issue?

Comment: set ur windows taskbar in autohide mode...

Comment: @RishadAppat I'm not familiar with auto-hide mode, because its make issues in another applications, plus if the wizard too big, even buttons will be under the task bar, right? :|.

Comment: @RishadAppat kind of issues in rendering and re-size, and on some full screen apps the taskbar come out while it should stay behind, anyway I just don't like to keep taskbar hidden anyway.

Comment: as i hav seen in the screenshot, the buttons r visible under task bar... If you u put it in autohide mode, you can easily use it... or other possible way is change the position of the task bar to left ot right...

Comment: have you try to resize opened window ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana yes, and it's just jumpy the cursor changed to re-size mode, but its not re-sizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's old question but as @Ravi Rathore said, its bug for 1366x768 screen, its old bug but with low priority for Google -_-

Anyway there is a solution for it provided in their forum:

1. Open android studio.
2. Go to settings
3. Go to appearances.
4. Change the theme to windows

Here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=168828

Answer (score 0):

Well its not only the problem of yours but its a bug in the studio for 1366x768 resolution which is discussed in the forums so my suggestion is that use the tab keys to have a control on the keys that are beyond your cursor reach or you may use the autohide feature of your taskbar..

Comment: This what I do, count tab clicks to guess what the button that I'm highlighting but this really annoying anyway.

Comment: Yes seriously but i have posted this on the studio forums so they might consider this in the further updates ..chill :)

Comment: May you give me a link? P.S. I'm not who down voted you.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/androidstudioforum go and post it on this.. they are very attentive in listening to their developers

Comment: this is a small page, I really on doubt, is this an official page?

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- get new laptop, with specs more suitable for development
- set taskbar to autohide mode
- move  taskbar elsewhere (I personally prefer it on a side)